# Interfaces in Fortran

Tags: interface, fortran

I stumbled over a particular problem with interfaces while debugging some code, where a called subroutine has a dummy argument of rank 2 but an actual argument of rank 1. The resulting difference in the arguments resulted in an invalid read.

To reproduce I created a small program (ignore the comments `! <>` for now):

```
PROGRAM ptest
USE mtest                                  ! <>
IMPLICIT NONE

REAL, ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:) :: field
INTEGER :: n
REAL :: s

n = 10
ALLOCATE(field(n))
CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(field)

CALL stest(n, field, s)

WRITE(*,*) s

DEALLOCATE(field)
END PROGRAM
```

and a module

```
MODULE mtest                               ! <>
IMPLICIT NONE                              ! <>

CONTAINS                                   ! <>

    SUBROUTINE stest(n, field, erg)
        INTEGER :: n
        REAL, DIMENSION(n,n) :: field
        REAL :: erg

        erg = SUM(field)
    END SUBROUTINE
END MODULE                                 ! <>
```

As far as I understand, this subroutine gets an automatic (explicit?) interface from being placed in the module. The problem is, that the actual `field` has length `10`, while the subroutine sums a field of length `10x10=100` which is clearly visible in `valgrind` as an invalid read.

Then I tested this same code without the module, i.e. all lines marked with `! <>` got removed/commented. As a result, gfortran's `-Wimplicit-interface` threw a warning, but the code worked as before.

So my question is: What is the best way, to deal with such a situation? Should I always place a generic interface à la

```
INTERFACE stest
    MODULE PROCEDURE stest
END INTERFACE
```

in the module? Or should I replace the definition of field with an deferred-shape array (i.e. `REAL, ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:,:) :: field`)?

**EDIT:** To be more precise on my question, I don't want to solve this particular problem, but want to know, what to do, to get a better diagnostic output from the compiler.

E.g. the given code doesn't give an error message and does, in principle, produce a segmentation fault (though, the code doesn't notice it). Placing a generic interface produces at least an error, complaining, that no matching definition for `stest` is found, which is also not really helpful, especially in the case, where you don't have the source code. Only a deferred-shape array resulted in an understandable error message (rank mismatch).

And this is, were I'm wondering, why the automatic module interface doesn't give a similar warning/error message.

Comment: The simplest solution is to declare field as a rank two array in the main program. (i.e. `REAL, ALLOCATABLE, DIMENSION(:,:) :: field`.)  And allocate it as such, to the size used in the subroutine. Then the actual and dummy arguments are consistent.   Is there a reason that you don't want to do this?

Comment: You can also pass field(1) and get "sequence association".

Comment: Sequence association could be used, but the number of elements mismatch also has to be fixed.  rank-1 100 elements could match rank-2 10x10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler cannot warn you, because the code is legal! You just pass wrong `n` and a non-square number of points. For explicit shape arrays you are responsible for correct dimensions. Consider

```
ALLOCATE(field(1000))

CALL stest(10, field, s)
```

this code will work although the number of elements of the actual and dummy arguments is not the same. Maybe suggest to gfortran developers to check whether the dummy argument is not larger, but I am not sure how difficult that is.

The generic interface causes the compiler to check the TKR rules. No sequence association of arrays of different rank is allowed and the compilation will fail. Therefore it will disable all legal uses of passing arrays of different rank to explicit shape and assumed size dummy arguments and limit your possibilities.

What is the solution? Use explicit shape arrays for situations they are good for and use assumed shape arrays otherwise (possibly with the `contiguous` attribute). The generic interface might help too, but changes the semantics and limits the possible use.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Now, I have to tell my coworker, who produced this code, what to do in the future... I didn't really think about the fact, that it could be completely valid code, because e.g. the generic interface does complain.